# Free cell alignment in a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align, tabu

I want to use the package `tabu` which I've heard is the latest and greatest package for creating tables to generate a table that looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------
|A          |     B     |          C| 
|           |           |           | 
|           |           |           | 
-------------------------------------
|           |           |           | 
|A          |     B     |          C| 
|           |           |           | 
-------------------------------------
|           |           |           | 
|           |           |           | 
|A          |     B     |          C| 
-------------------------------------
```

It is a simple table but the text in each cell is aligned differently. The package documentation says that `X` columns can be aligned both vertically (using `p`, `m`, `b`) and horizontally (using `l`, `c`, `r`, `j`) at the same time but I cannot find a way to use this feature to create this table. I know that it is always possible to use some low-level commands such as `\parbox` for this purpose but I'm very interested to know if there is a better way to do it.

If there is any other package that can create such a table or help with alignment please discuss it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) ia a dangerous package to use; it has many bugs and its not maintained; besides, the new version will be incompatible with the current one. My advise at this point is not to use `tabu` (See [`this thread`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.text.tex/tabu$20bug/comp.text.tex/xRGJTC74uCI/anwgH1lFGZkJ) at *c.t.t*).

You can simply use the [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package to declare some columns type and then `\multicolumn` can be of help to switch from one type to another:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[4]{
  >{\vspace{0pt}\minipage[c][#2][#3]{3cm}%
      \ifx#4r\relax\raggedright
        \else
      \ifx#4l\relax\raggedleft
        \else
      \ifx#4c\relax\centering
      \fi\fi\fi
    }p{#1}
  <{\endminipage\vspace{\tabcolsep}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|L{3cm}{3cm}{t}{r}|L{3cm}{3cm}{t}{c}|L{3cm}{3cm}{t}{l}|}
\hline
A  & B & C \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|L{3cm}{3cm}{c}{r}|}{A} 
& \multicolumn{1}{L{3cm}{3cm}{c}{c}|}{B} 
& \multicolumn{1}{L{3cm}{3cm}{c}{l}|}{C} 
\tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|L{3cm}{3cm}{b}{r}|}{A} 
& \multicolumn{1}{L{3cm}{3cm}{b}{c}|}{B} 
& \multicolumn{1}{L{3cm}{3cm}{b}{l}|}{C} 
\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The syntax for the `L` column type is

```
L{<width>}{<height>}{<v. position>}{<text justification>}
```

where `<width>` and `<height>` control the width and height of cell, `<v. position>` is the vertical position of text inside the cell (possible values: `t` top, `c` center, `b`, bottom), and `<text justification>` controls the justification of the text inside the cell (possible values: `l` raggedleft, `c` centered, `r` raggedright).

Comment: That's a brilliant solution, thanks Gonzalo. I didn't know tabu is not reliable yet!

Comment: @farhad0011 You're welcome. Yes, it's a shame about `tabu`. By the way, don't forget that you can accept the answer that you consider best solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to its left; You've already up-voted answers, but accepting is a different action. For more information, please read [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one TikZ-based answer, which I have adapted from some Sudoko-generating code due to Roberto Bonvallet (source: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/sudoku/).

```
% Original author: Roberto Bonvallet
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{row}
\newcounter{col}

\newcommand\setrow[9]{
  \setcounter{col}{1}
  \foreach \n in {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9} {
    \edef\x{\value{col} - 0.5}
    \edef\y{9.5 - \value{row}}
    \node[anchor=center] at (\x, \y) {\n};
    \stepcounter{col}
  }
  \stepcounter{row}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[scale=3] (0, 0) grid (3, 3);

    \setcounter{row}{1}
    \setrow {A}{ }{ }  { }{B}{ }  { }{ }{C}
    \setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
    \setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }

    \setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
    \setrow {A}{ }{ }  { }{B}{ }  { }{ }{C}
    \setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }

    \setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
    \setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
    \setrow {A}{ }{ }  { }{B}{ }  { }{ }{C}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks John for your solution, however, I'm interested to do this using table packages not with tikz. This table is just an example and in reality cells could have more than a single letter in them.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the package `cals`. The documentation "[Ex­am­ples of use](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cals/examples/demo.pdf)" page 3 shows the table you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,cals}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{xcolor,cals}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\bbrow{\brow\setbox\cals@current@row=\hbox{\vbox to 3cm{}}}
\newenvironment{decotable}{\begin{calstable}
  \Large\cals@setpadding{Ag}\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
  \cals@paddingL=0pt \relax
  \cals@paddingR=0pt \relax
  \def\cals@framecs@width{2pt}
  \def\cals@rs@width{8pt}
  \def\cals@cs@width{4pt}
  }{\end{calstable}}

\begin{decotable}
  \colwidths{{3cm}{3cm}{3cm}}
  \bbrow
  \cell{left,\\top}
  \alignC \cell{center,\\top}
  \def\cals@borderL{0pt}\def\cals@borderB{0pt}
  \alignR \cell{right,\\top} \erow
  \let\cals@borderL=\relax \let\cals@borderB=\relax
  \bbrow
  \alignL \cell{\vfil left,\\middle}
  \alignC \cell{\vfil center,\\middle}
  \alignR \cell{\vfil right,\\middle} \erow
  \bbrow
  \def\cals@bgcolor{green}
  \alignL \cell{\vfill left,\\bottom}
  \def\cals@bgcolor{}
  \alignC \cell{\vfill center,\\bottom}
  \alignR \cell{\vfill right,\\bottom} \erow
\end{decotable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sounds a promising package for tables :) thanks